# not able to set the visible property of button in one form from another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I need to interact with controls on other forms. Trying to access the controls by using, for example, the following...

i am accessing Backupform  control from form2

in backupform : I have defined like this....

```
public partial class BackupForm
{
 public bool ControlIsVisible
 {
  get { return this.btnrestore.Visible; }
  set {this.btnrestore.Visible = value; }
 }

 public BackupForm()
 {

  InitializeComponent();
  cbbackupforms.SelectedIndex = 0;
 // btnrestore.Enabled = false;
 }
}
```

i made the btnrestore properties `visible = true;` and `modifiers = private` in designer of backupform

and in form2 i am accessing the btnrestore visible  property

```
public partial class form2
{
  private Forms.BackupForm backs;

 public form2()
 {

  InitializeComponent();
  backs =  new Forms.BackupForm();
 }

 public void restore()
 {
      backs.ControlIsVisible = false;
 }  
}
```

but i am not able to visible  false for the button , would any one pls suggest any solution for this.....

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Just to make sure, are you actually calling your "restore" method?

Comment: i am sure  about that .....i am calling restore method.....

Comment: Can't reproduce it.  Problem is either not calling "restore" or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a reference to the instance of the first form, and use that reference to set properties of objects on that form. When you cast the object to Form1, the properties will be accesible.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling your Restore() method? Also, if all the Restore() method does is set the button's visible property on the seperate form, why not encapsaluate that method within your BackupForm object and call it using backs.Restore()?